# Will HTML pulled in asynchronously inherit the attributes of our Angular app's <head> and <meta> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, utf-8

In an Angular app, our index.html file has a `<head>` tag which sets the charset:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

When a user visits a certain page, that page's component makes an API call to fetch some HTML wrapped in a `<div>` tag, and that HTML is asynchronously loaded into the template via `[innerHTML]` property binding like

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHTMLfromApi"></div>
```

Will that data inherit the utf-8 charset (and other things) we set in index.html's meta tag(s)? Or is it too late, since that head tag and the rest of the app has already been rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I am not Angular developer but the javascript and html should be the same.

So lets say we try to use innerHtml.

First the [html tags need to pass through the angular](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-innerhtml-binding-angular) [html_sanitizer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/sanitization/html_sanitizer.ts) which mean some of the tags are dropped.

And if we are trying to inject the tags into the body tag like the next example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>Document2</title>
                <script>
                    console.log('test');
                </script>
            </head>
            <body></body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

the `html`, `body` and `head` tag disappear and the metadata is not overridden (title stay the same).

And the metadata tags stay within the body which is not good.

If we take the innerHtml outside to the html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document1</title>
    </head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>Document2</title>
                <script>
                    console.log('test');
                </script>
            </head>
            <body></body>
        </html>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The heads tags are merged into single head tag and the tags of the second `head` are below the tags of first `head` (title is not changed here as well).

So because the title is not changed in the examples above i assume it's inherit the metadata and if any new metadata somehow find its way into the html its not gonna override the existing metadata.